# Laravel 5.2 Queue and Jobs - Not Pushing to Jobs DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, curl, laravel-5

EDIT 2:

Here are the steps we are going through:

1. Schedule is Run (creating `CollectHistoricalData` Jobs for each company)
2. `CollectHistoricalData` should be pushed to Queue (`jobs` table)
3. `CollectHistoricalData` has a function `ApiDaemon::GetCompanyWithQuery($company, $query)` which is run from a separate class that is referenced a couple of other places too.
4. `GetCompanyWithQuery` collects the data and inserts it into the database.

It runs all the way through fine, but the hang up is rather than inserting the job into the jobs table, it just runs it synchronously, one after another.

---

EDIT 1:

The `.env` file is set to use the `database` `QUEUE_DRIVER`, I have even tried hard coding it in the `config/queue.php` file.

---

We are using Laravel 5.2 for a project. In this project, we are needing to every hour cURL a url and save the data to the database. We at first were using Cron Jobs and basically firing off thousands of cURLs in about a minute, which would crash PHP due to the load.

We decided to move over to Laravel's Jobs and Queues, without success. We are using the Database driver for our jobs, and have tried numerous different approaches to getting the jobs into the database, so the daemon workers we have can process them.

Here is our code right now, we are using the Kernel.php `$schedule` to start the thing off, so we don't have hundreds of requests attempting to happen an hour, which results in tens of thousands of cURLs.

Kernel.php Schedule:

```
    $schedule
        ->call(function () {
            $items = DB::select('{selecting certain things to run}');
            foreach ($items as $q) {
                $this->dispatch(new CollectHistoricalData(Company::find($q->company_id), ApiQuery::find($q->query_id)));
            }
        })
        ->hourly()
        ->name('Historical Pulls')
        ->withoutOverlapping()
        ->before(function() {
            $this->startTime = Carbon::now();
        })
        ->after(function () {
            mail({mail us a report afterward});
        });
```

When this runs, it is sitting there running them all one by one, rather than pushing them to the Jobs table that was created.

CollectHistoricalData.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Helpers\Daemons\ApiDaemon;
use App\Jobs\Job;
use App\Models\Company;
use App\Models\ApiQuery;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CollectHistoricalData extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $company, $query;


    /**
     * CollectHistoricalData constructor.
     * @param Company $company
     * @param ApiQuery $query
     */
    public function __construct(Company $company, ApiQuery $query)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
        $this->query = $query;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        mail({let us know what started and when});
        QueryDaemon::GetCompanyWithQuery($this->company, $this->query);
    }

    public function failed()
    {
        mail({mail us letting us know it failed});
    }


}
```

The job is referencing another class with the function inside it (since that code is a heafty beast all on its own), plus there are about 20 of these, so it is easiest to reference the class rather than recreating all 20 classes into Jobs.

TL;DR

We have a schedule that is supposed to push a job that references a function in another class, to the jobs table, but is rather running them one after another, slowly. What is causing this?

Comment: what's the `QUEUE_DRIVER` specified in your `.env` file?

Comment: The `QUEUE_DRIVER` is set to `database` in the `.env` file, plus I have even tried going as far as hard coding it that way in the `config/queue.php` file.

Comment: Is `Company::find($q->company_id)` and `ApiQuery::find($q->query_id)` doing work that should be queued? That's getting called immediately in your kernel, and just the result is being passed into the job class.

Comment: Yes it is, the company and apiQuery are being found every time, I see them processing and inserting the api information into the database, but it process them one at a time rather than pushing them into the queue.

Comment: Sounds like you need to move the `Company` and `ApiQuery` code into the `handle()` method of your queued job, that's the only way that will run after being queued.

Comment: Rather than moving all the code, we are referencing a function outside of the job class we made. I will edit the question, one second.

Comment: @jszobody, any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: Where's the `$this->dispatch` method coming from in your Kernel.php file, I don't think that file has a dispatch method by default?

Comment: We included the `DispatchesJobs` trait in the file. Along with `use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;` at the top.

Comment: I'd start tearing it down to the barebones then to troubleshoot. Get rid of constructor params, stick a `dd('I'm inside the handle method');` in there. Also `dd(config('queue.default'))` to make sure that's not getting changed anywhere.

Comment: I don't have any other ideas offhand, just gonna be a matter of boiling it down until you identify the issue.

Comment: See my answer.... I feel really.... really stupid right now...

Comment: ... which you would have found with a `dd(config('queue.default'))` check =)

Comment: That is exactly how I found out. I was running it on my local machine, not my server.... it said it on my local. I am running terminal, I thought I was on the server, but no... ugh....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well... I am dumb....

`php artisan config:clear`

I didn't clear the cache of the config.... wow...

Comment: This worked for me. I'm not sure what this did. Can someone explain?

Comment: @grez Your configuration info is probably cached in production, so you have to clear the cache in order to have changes take effect

Answer (score 8):

In Laravel 6.x , edit this in /env : QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync => QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
then handle data can insert jobs table

Answer (score 4):

As

```
php artisan config:clear
```

wasn't working for me i was able to make it work using:

```
php artisan config:cache
```